# post__not_in is not working as expected in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I was trying to insert a related post in single blog post. But the post__not_in in the argument during WP_Query is not excluding the current post from the category. Am I doing something wrong here. Please help me to resolve this issue. The below code I am using in the functions.php

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->id;
$cat_ids = array();
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

if(!empty($categories) && !is_wp_error($categories)):
    foreach ($categories as $category):
        array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
    endforeach;
endif;
  
$related = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post__not_in'    => array(1014),
        'posts_per_page'  => '1',
     )
);
$mr = "";
$mr .="<p style='background:#EAEAEA; padding:40px; color:#000;'>";
if ($related->posts) {
    
    foreach ($related->posts as $key => $delta) {
        $mr     .=  $delta->post_title;
        $image  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($delta->ID), 'medium');
        $mr  .= $image[0];
    }
}else{
    $mr .= 'No results!'; die;
}
$mr .="</p>";
```

Comment: Should you be hard coding the post ID (`array(1014),`)?

Comment: I am checking the post with the ID 1014 it's not getting excluded. I have intentionally did the hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

@nigel-ren alluded to this, but it sounds like you want to dynamically exclude the current post, in which case you would want:

```
'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
```

Your code currently is excluding, specifically, the post with ID 1014.

But, maybe you hard-coded 1014 for testing, and 1014 was not excluded?
If so, the reason is not apparent, but it might be helpful to look at the output from:

```
var_dump($related);
var_dump($related->get_posts());
```

Comment: You are right I have hard coded 1014 for testing. And the problem is it is not getting excluded when I load 1014 in single page.

Comment: @HybridDeveloper could you try those var_dumps suggested in the answer and share with us in case that helps us spot something?